# How to make a C# loading class as generic as possible

Tags: c#, loading

I have this class, that is supposed to receive a Control, set a new PictureBox (loading gif) and start a new BackGroundWorker. I need to pass a function/method to the BackGroundWorker.DoWork() to work and then close the thread once it is finished. My problem is that I dont know how to make this as generic as possible. Now I want to pass a function with 1 argument, but tommorow I may need to pass 2 arguments or maybe no argument at all (void).

Any help would be apreciated.

Tanks

```
   class Loading
{
    private BackgroundWorker _bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private Control _control { get; set; }        
    private PictureBox _pic = new PictureBox() { Image = Properties.Resources.loading};

    public Loading(Control control,  VERY GENERIC METHOD)
    {
        _control = control;
        _bw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _control.Invoke(new EventHandler(StartLoading));
        };

        _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            _control.Invoke(new EventHandler(StopLoading));                
        };

        _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    }

    private void StartLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _control.Controls.Add(_pic);
        _bw.RunWorkerAsync();            
    }

    private void StopLoading(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       this.Dispose();   
        _control.Controls.Remove(_pic);
    }
```

}

Comment: You might want to look into [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx), and add a generic argument to your class.

Comment: How would the additional arguments being used? Do you know about the `params` keyword for function arguments?

Comment: The entire purpose of using a BGW is that it handles marshaling code to the UI on your behalf.  You don't need to invoke in the completed handler, and you should be starting the loading from the UI thread in the body of `Loading`, not in the `DoWork` handler.  Starting the worker in the `DoWork` method is rather pointless.

Comment: As an aside, `_bw` and `_pic` should be marked as `readonly` to declar their intent of not being modified outside of the initializer. This makes your code more robust and has the added benefit that the runtime may be able to make certain optimizations based on the knowledge of those being invariant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just accept an `Action`.  Your code here has no information that it needs to pass into the method, nor does it need a result.  If the caller has variables that they want to use within the implementation of the delegate they can use a lambda to close over the variable(s) on their end.

It's as easy as:

```
new Loading(someControl, () => SomeMethod(someVariable, someOtherVariable));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
public Loading(Control control,  Action work)
{
    _control = control;
    _bw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _control.Invoke(new EventHandler(StartLoading));
        work();
    };

    _bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, e) =>
    {
        _control.Invoke(new EventHandler(StopLoading));                
    };

    _bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}
```

Comment: It should be something similar to this... but this always assume my methods have no parameters... and if I want a parameter, or 2 ?

Comment: Use a delegate with signature `void Work(params object[] args)` instead of `void Action()`. You won't need it unless the arguments point to class references with data that changes. Logically you will receive a snapshot of the data at the start of work wrapped in the `Action()` delegate.

Comment: Look at the answer by @Servy for example on how to wrap arguments into an `Action()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the pattern used by .NET ThreadPool and make "VERY GENERIC METHOD" a generic method that takes an object as a single argument.  The method would need to know what the object is and what to cast it to.

Comment: Could you please give a example ?